# First integral definition help

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I just started my pde book about a week ago. It gave me the problem

$$xu_x + yu_y + xy(z^2 + 1)u_z = 0$$

The book says to take a first integral, and defines a first integral as "A function $u$ in $C_1(\Omega)$ is a first integral of vector field $V(R, Q, P)$"   What does this definition mean?

Comment: Your definition appears to be incomplete. "$u$ is a first integral of $V(R,Q,P)$ if ..."

Comment: In general, if you have an ode which depends on time, a first integral $G$ is a function such that $G \circ u$ does not depend on time for any solution $u$ to the ode.

Answer (score 0):

$$xu_x+yu_y+xy(z^2+1)u_z=0$$
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{xy(z^2+1)}=\frac{du}{0}$$
$$ydx=xdy=\frac{dz}{z^2+1}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $du=0$ :
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $ydx=xdy$ :
$$\frac{y}{x}=c_2$$
A third characteristic equation comes from solving $ydx=xdy=\frac{ydx+xdy}{2}=\frac{dz}{z^2+1}$ :
$$2\arctan(z)-xy=c_3$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_1=F(c_2,c_3)$ is then obtained :
$$\boxed{u(x,y,z)=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\:,\:\left(2\arctan(z)-xy\right)\right)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.

If some sufficient boundary conditions are specified in the wording of the problem, one determines the fonction $F$ and obtain the explicit solution $u(x,y,z)$.